# identity server use client secret from javascript

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

I'm using identity server 3 and want to know if there is any risk using client secret from JavaScript to be able to use Password token grant.

**Edit**
answer from Scott Brady

Then you'll also know that the implicit flow returns an access token and that the ROPC flow is insecure and deprecated. By stealing a client secret, other apps can impersonate your app, making phishing very simple. Your token endpoint becomes a public endpoint that anyone can use to validate your user's credentials https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's JavaScript running in the browser, then your secret is not secret anymore.

JavaScript running in the browser is considered a public client. The implicit flow was explicitly designed for your scenario.

Comment: Yes I understand that and understand as well that  the OpenId is the best choice. 

the issue I'm facing  is my customer need a login password page and all api works well with access_token

Comment: the good question is, what can a malicious user do with that secret because in all cases he needs a user password to get a token.

Comment: Then you'll also know that the implicit flow returns an access token and that the ROPC flow is insecure and deprecated. By stealing a client secret, other apps can impersonate your app, making phishing very simple. Your token endpoint becomes a public endpoint that anyone can use to validate your user's credentials https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Comment: thanks for your answer , I didn't got that point of view before. 

can you please answer my other question please ?